# Specify exit code in batch exit

Tags: batch-file, exit-code

I need to specify my own exit code in my batch script when it successful exits on a if exist clause. As you will notice, I specified it as an `exit 5`, I have also tried `exit /b 5` but nothing has worked. Any suggestions?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

set SOURCE_PARENT=%1
set FOLDER=%2
set TARGET_FILE=%3

net use S: %SOURCE_PARENT% 
net use T: %TARGET_FILE%

if exist T:\%FOLDER% (
  echo Folder exists, process exiting
  net use S: /Delete /y
  net use T: /Delete /y
  exit 5
) else (
  mkdir T:\%FOLDER%
)

xcopy S:\%FOLDER% T:\%FOLDER% /E /I /H

net use S: /Delete /y
net use T: /Delete /y

exit
```

Comment: Why do you think it did not work? did you try to check errorlevel after calling the script?

Comment: it has to `exit /b 5`.How do call iy?From another batch?

Comment: I have the exit code returned to my java which is calling it. In debugging, the exit code remains a 0

Comment: Show us how you are calling it from your Java code.

Comment: Then it is more related to java, not to batch...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a script script.bat containing:

```
@echo off
echo Hello from script.
exit /b 5
```

In the command prompt or from another script call

```
test.bat
echo %errorlevel%
```

It should show:

> C:\Temp>script.bat
>
> Hello from script.
>
> C:\Temp>echo %errorlevel%
>
> 5

Comment: This explains the difference between ERRORLEVEL (the exit code) and %ERRORLEVEL% (the environment variable): [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=20743)