# How to set timeout for a command in cmd

Tags: batch-file, timeout

I want to run a command, and if it does not complete in 1 sec I want it to return 31744.

Example:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\my_django_stuff>mycommand < input.txt > output txt 
timeout /t 1
```

This gives me a syntax error, and if the running time of my command is infinite, then it is also not stopping after 1 sec.

Answer (score 3):

```
start "UniqueWindowTitle" mycommand < input.txt > output txt
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq UniqueWindowTitle" /f |find " PID " && (
   echo task was killed.
   exit /b 31744
) || (
   echo there was no task to kill.
   echo it terminated in time.
)
```

Sadly `taskkill` does not return a useful errorlevel, so we parse the output (if the task was killed, it's `SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 12345`.
Dependent on your actual application you might or might not need the `/f` parameter ("Force")

I replaced `timeout` with `ping-n 2 localhost`, because `timeout 1` does actually not wait 1 second, but until "next second" arrives - which could be only some milliseconds in extreme situations.

Also, I didn't look for "SUCCESS" but for " PID " to keep it language independent. (there is no `PID`, when the process was no found).

Comment: You shouldn't use `ping` here I think. The only reason I used `timeout` was just because `taskkill` command may last something less than half an one second.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
@echo off

start "custom" mycommand < input.txt > output txt 
timeout /t 1
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq custom" /FI "IMAGENAME eq mycommand" /f | findstr /c:"PID" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Task was killed!
    pause>nul
    exit /b 0
) else (
    echo The task was killed successfully! Will exit with code your_custom_code
    pause>nul
    exit /b your_custom_code
)
```

Now, you are sure that the program has been terminated (**f**orcibly).

- See how to exit with a specific exit code from batch files: [Specify exit code in batch exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21338903)

Please note that here we use `timeout` instead of `ping` as it will surely last something less than 1/4 seconds. So, as `taskkill` will last a bit, you will have surely something more than 1 second.

Comment: By using start custom it is opening new window named 'custom'. I just want to time my command : mycommand < input.txt > output.txt   to 1 sec and if does not complete in one second it should end automatically.